# Adding a multiple choice ques with goToPage

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to add a multiple choice question with a goToPage setting.  I have followed the documentation and I cannot figure out if I found a bug or doing something wrong.

I get an error at this line, and I don't know why:        
`var choice1 = ques.createChoice(name1, page1Item);  //Error:  InternalError: Cannot find method createChoice(string,Item).`

```
function testCreateChoice(){
  // documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item#createchoicevalue-navigationitem

  // define variables
  var mcId = 1310873270;  //Id of multiple choice queston
  var pageId1 = 1255540175; //Id of page 2
  var pageId2 = 1103976777; //Id of page 3
  var name1 = "Go To Page 2";
  var name2 = "Go To Page 3";

  // open question and itmes
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getFormUrl());
  var ques = form.getItemById(mcId).asMultipleChoiceItem();
  var page1Item = form.getItemById(pageId1);
  var page2Item = form.getItemById(pageId2);

  //verify
  Logger.log(ques.getTitle());  // correctly itentified
  Logger.log(page1Item.getTitle()); // correctly itentified
  Logger.log(page2Item.getTitle()); // correctly itentified

  //add Choices  ~ This is where I get the error
  var choice1 = ques.createChoice(name1, page1Item);  //Error:  InternalError: Cannot find method createChoice(string,Item).
  var choice2 = ques.createChoice(name2, page2Item);  //Error:  InternalError: Cannot find method createChoice(string,Item).
  var newChoices =[choice1,choice2];
  ques.setChoices(newChoices);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Funny, I found another post, that I helped someone answer a similar question.  After you write so much code, you forget your own answers.

The solution was to add `.asPageBreakItem();` to the end of get item for page1Item and page1Item.

```
  var page1Item = form.getItemById(pageId1).asPageBreakItem();
  var page2Item = form.getItemById(pageId2).asPageBreakItem();
```